# Отправка POST с токеном в Java

Tags: java, fxml

Я разрабатываю `JavaFX` десктоп-приложение и столкнулся с проблемой парсинга данных, которую решает dadata.

В описании их `api` расписано как подключаться к ним. Но мне не удалось найти пример, как подключиться через (например) библиотеку `URLConnection` с указанием токенов (`API`-ключ, секретный ключ), а пример с сайта dadatа это интеграция из SpringBoot, что мне не подходит.

Может кто подсказать в какую сторону необходимо искать?

Comment: ничего непонятно, но очень интересно... "Проблема типизации данных" - какая-то новая проблема для джавы? Я разрабатываю fxml десктоп-приложение - это что за зверь такой? JavaFX чтоли? Что такое dadata и зачем это вообще нужно? Каким образом вы умудрились затолкать спринг в десктопное приложение? И куда, имея такой зоопарк технологий, вы прикрутили еще и какой-то Apache (тоже непонятно что именно это такое, потому как апач в целом разработал вот это все: https://projects.apache.org/projects.html)? в общем нужен код. на сугубо теоретический вопрос вряд ли можно получить практический ответ

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо, уточнил вопрос. Зоопарка у меня там пока нет, все в нормах приличия. Spring есть на сайте дадаты как пример интеграции, но мне даже с ним не удалось разобраться.
Код я не вижу смысла прикреплять тк там в цикле просто список экземпляров и берется поле, которое нужно отправить на api дадаты и получить стандартизированную запись этих данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне удалось найти решение, надо было просто разобраться со структурой самого запроса: токены указываются в заголовке, но для dadata не надо указывать длину тела запроса, поэтому через `HttpURLConnection` это будет выглядеть так:

```
        int postDataLength = fiasAddress.length();
        String response="";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(_URL);
            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput( true );
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token "+_APIkey);
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-Secret", _SecretKey);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            String inputString = "[\""+fiasAddress+"\"]";
            byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("utf-8");

            try(OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
                os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            }

            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;){
                response += c;
            }
            return response;
        }
```